# IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.maximumSize(I)Lcom/google/common/collect/MapMaker;

Tags: clojure, datomic

Anyone recognize what might be the cause of this error? It's from a lein clojure project that uses `datomic-pro 0.9.5372`. It only shows up in my production environment. I'm still trying to reproduce in my dev environment.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.maximumSize(I)Lcom/google/common/collect/MapMaker; from class datomic.datalog__init, compiling:(datomic_session.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
    at sonacamp.router$eval20$loading__5569__auto____21.invoke(router.clj:1)
    at sonacamp.router$eval20.invokeStatic(router.clj:1)
    at sonacamp.router$eval20.invoke(router.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at user$eval5$fn__7.invoke(form-init5043920914949880861.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init5043920914949880861.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init5043920914949880861.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.maximumSize(I)Lcom/google/common/collect/MapMaker; from class datomic.datalog__init
    at datomic.datalog__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at datomic.datalog__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2168)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2177)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2196)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:703)
    at datomic.query$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(query.clj:4)
    at datomic.query__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at datomic.query__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2168)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2177)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2196)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at datomic.api$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(api.clj:6)
    at datomic.api__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at datomic.api__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2168)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2177)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2196)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at datomic_session$eval3591$loading__5569__auto____3592.invoke(datomic_session.clj:1)
    at datomic_session$eval3591.invokeStatic(datomic_session.clj:1)
    at datomic_session$eval3591.invoke(datomic_session.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    ... 70 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had a very outdated dependency `[datomic-session]` that I forgot I was experimenting with. Removing that resolved the issue. Turned out I had the dependency installed via `checkouts/`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably have a different version of google commons than datomic was compiled against. Check the output of `lein deps :tree`, and see if there are conflicts related to that library.